# How to generate vCard file through python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, outlook, pypi

I want to write a script which does save user information like name , contact number etc as a vCard in the form of a file .
Is there any library for it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vobject` can do this. See [the project description on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vobject) or the [project homepage](http://eventable.github.io/vobject/) for details.